# Regex extra in Hive after particular string

Tags: json, regex, hive, hiveql

I am very bad with Regex extract. I am trying to get the string which is marked in bold. Basically everything after `cardUUID':u'` till next `'`

> '{u'cardName': u'Hilton Garden Inn Macon/Mercer University',
>   u'cardUUID': u'**a99512ea-c875-4aaa-8b0d-bb8dd668aaa8**',
>   u'attributionId': u'29fb392a-b4b6-ffab-d7e8-45e9d470e585', u'title':
>   {u'content': u'Hilton Garden Inn Macon/Mercer University', u'type':
>   u'title'}, u'cardSubtype': u'GETAWAYS_MARKET_RATE', u'slot_1':
>   {u'content': u'Macon, Georgia', u'type': u'location-and-distance'},
>   u'value': {u'content': u'$135', u'type': u'price'}}'

I tried couple of things in regex it did not work. Any suggestions? I am using Hive

Comment: what's the datatype of the column?

Comment: Assuming the language you're using AND the regex engine supports positive lookbehind __(?<=u'attributionId': u')[^']+__

If it works, i can explain it as an aswer.

Comment: I am using Hive and data type is string .

Comment: @lucas_7_94 can i use regex_extract function here ?

Comment: Assuming the function works as i have in mind, it would work, i would try. The pattern works in regex101.

Answer (score 1):

Using `get_json_object`:

Check original string:

```
 select  '{u\'cardName\': u\'Cortyard Greenbelt\', u\'cardUUID\': u\'cfcc39d4-24d1-40b2-84b5-9aaab263fa0e\', u\'attribtionId\': u\'29fb392a-95fd-268f-7f84-7a58a7494c35\', u\'title\': {\'content\': \'Cortyard Greenbelt\', \'type\': \'title\'}, \'cardSbtype\': \'GETAWAYS_MARKET_RATE\', \'slot_1\': {\'content\': \'Greenbelt, Maryland\', \'type\': \'location-and-distance\'}, \'vale\': {\'content\': \'$140\', \'type\': \'price\'}}' as json;
OK
{u'cardName': u'Cortyard Greenbelt', u'cardUUID': u'cfcc39d4-24d1-40b2-84b5-9aaab263fa0e', u'attribtionId': u'29fb392a-95fd-268f-7f84-7a58a7494c35', u'title': {'content': 'Cortyard Greenbelt', 'type': 'title'}, 'cardSbtype': 'GETAWAYS_MARKET_RATE', 'slot_1': {'content': 'Greenbelt, Maryland', 'type': 'location-and-distance'}, 'vale': {'content': '$140', 'type': 'price'}}
Time taken: 2.38 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Now remove `u` and replace `'` with `"` and extract JSON element:

```
hive> select get_json_object(regexp_replace(json,'(u\')|\'','"'),'$.cardUUID') cardUUID
    > from
    > (
    > select  '{u\'cardName\': u\'Cortyard Greenbelt\', u\'cardUUID\': u\'cfcc39d4-24d1-40b2-84b5-9aaab263fa0e\', u\'attribtionId\': u\'29fb392a-95fd-268f-7f84-7a58a7494c35\', u\'title\': {\'content\': \'Cortyard Greenbelt\', \'type\': \'title\'}, \'cardSbtype\': \'GETAWAYS_MARKET_RATE\', \'slot_1\': {\'content\': \'Greenbelt, Maryland\', \'type\': \'location-and-distance\'}, \'vale\': {\'content\': \'$140\', \'type\': \'price\'}}' as json
    > )s;
OK
cfcc39d4-24d1-40b2-84b5-9aaab263fa0e
Time taken: 0.184 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

If the string contains leading and trailing `'` like in your post, they should be removed.

Comment: I used below query Select get_json_object(json, '$.cardUUID') from (

 select regexp_replace(wc_data_json,'u','') json ,wc_data_json
from my table) a

Comment: The regex_replace works and provides a json as below {'cardName': 'Cortyard Greenbelt', 'cardUUID': 'cfcc39d4-24d1-40b2-84b5-9aaab263fa0e', 'attribtionId': '29fb392a-95fd-268f-7f84-7a58a7494c35', 'title': {'content': 'Cortyard Greenbelt', 'type': 'title'}, 'cardSbtype': 'GETAWAYS_MARKET_RATE', 'slot_1': {'content': 'Greenbelt, Maryland', 'type': 'location-and-distance'}, 'vale': {'content': '$140', 'type': 'price'}}  But the get_json_object returns null

Comment: @SAM244776 fixed and tested

Answer (score 0):

Positive lookbehind and lookahead with lazy matching:

```
(?<='cardUUID': u').*?(?=')
```

Check: https://regexr.com/42jru

Comment: I tried this regexp_extract(example,'\(?<=\'cardUUID\': u\'\).*?(?=\'\)',1) which returned null